# How to build a webpage with multiple autoplay and loop video tags (mp4 files)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mp4, autoplay

I’m looking for ways to make a web page containing many video tags within it.
These mp4 videos are short, about 7 seconds and a size of about 100KB, they are looped and autoplayed.

Here is an example of the video tag I'm using:

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
   <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The problem is that many times (especially on mobile devices), not all videos are loaded correctly. Sometimes they don’t appear at all, sometimes they appear but they don’t play. The number of videos that are uploaded correctly varies with each refresh, and not always the same videos are loaded correctly. This makes me think it is not an issue of mp4 files.

**The question is**
Is there a way to ensure that each video is loaded correctly and is autoplayed?
Can it be a correct approach to force loading with javascript if the video is not loaded correctly, and then play it?
Is there a way to achieve this or is it impossible? Maybe a js library?

I tried to force play through javascript, after a period of time after the page is loaded, but it didn't work

Example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myVideo.play();
}, 5000);
```

Thanks in advance